# What do I need to send text messages with Kannel?

Tags: php, sms, kannel

I want to be able to send text messages from Linux with PHP.  I've read about and installed Kannel, a free SMS gateway.  When I try to use the HTTP interface, it won't send a message.  Do I need something else to send text messages via kannel, like a modem?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I know Kannel is a pain to setup

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need a GSM modem and a SIM card from your local mobile network provider.

To setup your GSM modem, you can auto-detect its settings using [`wvdialconf`](http://www.google.com/search?q=wvdialconf).  The output contains pertinent information such as Baud rate, which serial port is used, and the modem's initialization string.

To test that your modem works properly, you can use [`minicom`](http://www.google.com/search?q=minicom).  Minicom acts as a terminal to any serial device (in this case, a GSM modem) and, with it, you can send [AT commands](http://gatling.ikk.sztaki.hu/~kissg/gsm/at+c.html) to your modem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is a solution, but [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com) provides a very easy to use HTML api for sending sms messages anywhere in the world.  I'v been using them for several years.  You only pay for the sms messages you send.